# Modulus Division in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm feeling a little overwhelmed with this. The question and the start of my code is below. Could someone tell me if this is going in the right track? If not, could you help? Any suggestions is appreciated. Thank you in advance. (This is not my final code, just the beginning of the problem).

A customer needs a specific amount of paper. The charges on the paper are $0.10 
for single sheets, $0.055 per sheet for amounts in multiples of 100 sheets, $0.04
per sheet in multiples of 500 sheets and $0.03 per sheet in multiples of 1000 
sheets. Develop a solution to calculate the type and number of packages for the 
least amount of money the customer should buy, given the amount of sheets the 
customer needs. For example, if the customer needs 380 sheets, the amount she 
would pay when buying in multiples of 100 would be $22.00. However, if the 
customer bought 500 sheets the cost would be $20.00. Therefore, it would be cost 
effective for the customer to buy a package of 500 sheets.
(Hint: Use modulus division (Mod) to find the remainder of a division).

```
Imports System

Module Paper

    Sub Main()

      Dim Name as String
      Dim OrderNumber as String
      Dim Paper as Integer
      Dim Thousandpaper as Integer
      Dim FiveHundredPaper as Integer
      Dim FirstCut as Integer
      Dim SecondCUt as Integer

      'User Input Begins Here:
      Console.WriteLine("Hello! What is your name?")
      Name = console.readline()

      Console.WriteLine("Please enter a order number:")
      OrderNumber = console.readline()

      Console.WriteLine("Finally ,how much paper would you like?")
      Paper = console.readline()

      If (Paper > 1000)
        Thousandpaper = (Paper / 1000)
      End If

      If (Thousandpaper) > Paper Then
        GoTo 44
      End If

      FirstCut = (Paper mod 1000)

      If (FirstCut > 500)
        FiveHundredPaper= (FirstCut / 500)
      End If

      SecondCut = (FirstCut / 500)      

      44: Console.WriteLine("1000 paper pack:")
      Console.WriteLine(Thousandpaper)      
      Console.WriteLine("500 paper pack:")
      Console.WriteLine(FirstCut)                  

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: `GOTO`!  I haven't seen one of those un-ironically in years.  Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

It makes sense to take the advice from @Heinzi's answer first. I'm only able to make a sensible attempt at a "Top Down" approach because I already appreciate how the core algorithm should be structured.

---

Here is some object orientation to get you started.

```
Public Structure PaperPackage
    Public Size As Integer
    Public PricePerSheet As 
End Structure

Dim availablePackages = New List(of PaperPackage) _
    { _
        New PaperPackage With { .Size = 1000, .PricePerSheet = 0.03 }, _
        New PaperPackage With { .Size = 500, .PricePerSheet = 0.04 }, _
        New PaperPackage With { .Size = 100, .PricePerSheet = 0.055 }, _
        New PaperPackage With { .Size = 1, .PricePerSheet = 0.1 } _
    }
```

Then you probably want to write a function with a signature something like this,

```
Public Shared Function CheapestPaperChoices( _
    availableChoices As IList(of PaperPackage), _
    requiredSheets As Integer) As IDictionary(Of PaperPackage, Integer)
```

Which would return an `IDictionary` containing each paper package that is required and an `Integer` count for the quantity.

To offer a little more help, you'll proably find that if you write the function,

```
Public Structure PackagesThatFitResult
    Public Quantity As Integer
    Public NewRemainingSheets As Integer 
End Structure

Private Shared Function PackagesThatFit( _
    remainingSheets As Integer, _
    package As PaperPackage) As PackagesThatFitResult
```

you could call it iteratively in the function I specified above.

Just one last warning, you may find it pays to over purchase with a larger package, if say, your last remainder is 49 sheets.

Answer (score 6):

Let me give you a few general hints:

1. Modulus in VB.NET is done using the [Mod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx) operator. This answers the question in your title, but it won't help you with your immediate problem.
2. Stop coding. Take a sheet of paper and try to solve the problem from a mathematic point of view. Try to find an algorithm (in pseudo-code) for the optimization that is requested in your problem statment.
3. Only once you have your algorithm *and* you are fairly sure that it is correct, start implementing it in the language of your choice (VB.NET).